# XNA Texture2D Billboarding appears as a white block

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, 3d, xna, texture2d

Very odd problem, when I try and draw my billboard sprite it always appears as a white block, changing the .draw color property still draws it as white, it also doesn't matter it I use a jpeg, or transparent png.

[EDIT]

So I'm now trying to use a `Viewport` instead of a basic effect to just get an x and y screen coordinate, I'll fix any scaling issue later, however now the image stays in the exact same spot (on the screen, it doesn't change position based on the camera) and doesn't get any bigger or smaller based on how far away it is

My new billboard rendering function:

```
public void Draw(Camera camera, GraphicsDevice device, SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D Texture)
{
    Viewport viewport = new Viewport(new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 480));
    Vector3 viewSpaceTextPosition = viewport.Project(this.position, camera.Projection, camera.View, camera.World);

    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, new Vector2(viewSpaceTextPosition.X, viewSpaceTextPosition.Y), null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(Texture.Bounds.Center.X, Texture.Bounds.Center.Y), this.Scale, SpriteEffects.None, viewSpaceTextPosition.Z);
    spriteBatch.End();

    device.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
    device.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
    device.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
}
```

So is my use of Viewport wrong or do I just need to use it's information differently in `spriteBatch.Draw()`?

Comment: what happens if you change "Texture.Bounds" by "null" in draw call?

Comment: Still exactly the same, the image used is 256x256 and draws fine if I draw it in 2D space as normal like a UI overlay, is there a specific bit depth that WP7 XNA requires for images in 3D space?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that what you are doing with basic effect is not right... it would be much better and easier to work with spritebatch as usual and use viewport.Project to get the 3d point projected to 2D screen position

Comment: Actually no, I did something very catastrophically wrong, look to my edits in the question

Comment: Regarding your first version (which seemed to provide the correct position?): Does it help to set the texture on the effect?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but no, it remained white, the same file works perfectly if you use it in just the usual old 2D sprite drawing

Comment: Scratch that last, it helps if you put `basicEffect.TextureEnabled = true;` BEFORE you apply the texture... derp! If you submit that as an answer then I'll mark it as so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, you have to enable textures on the effect and then set `effect.Texture` to the Texture2D you want to use just before calling `spriteBatch.Begin()` in the draw function

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick using viewport project... taking two projection points and calculating its distance you get a value affected by depth... so if it's deeper that value will be smaller.

```
public void Draw(Camera camera, GraphicsDevice device, SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D Texture)
{
     Vector3 pos1= device.Viewport.Project(
          this.position, 
          camera.Projection, camera.View, camera.World);
     Vector3 pos2= device.Viewport.Project(
          this.position+ Vactor3.UnitY*10, 
          camera.Projection, camera.View, camera.World);
     Vector2 pos = new Vector2(pos1.X, pos1.Y);
     Vector2 origin = new Vector2(Texture.Bounds.Center.X, Texture.Bounds.Center.Y);
     float Scale = Vector3.Distance(pos1, pos2) * CustomRatio;

     spriteBatch.Begin();
     spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, pos, null, Color.White, 0, 
                      origin, Scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
     spriteBatch.End();

    device.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
    device.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
    device.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
}
```

In other hand... your previous code seems to be extracted from a source that drinks from this article made by the guy behind Xna that explain how to use basiceffect to draw billboards in 3D with spritebatch...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/01/12/spritebatch-billboards-in-a-3d-world.aspx

I hope it helps you

Comment: Exactly the same result as my code in the question, the position of the sprite on the screen simply just doesn't change when the camera moves :<

Comment: are you sure that you use the same camera? are you rendering all with the same camera?

Comment: Here you assume that `Vector3.UnitY` is parallel to the screen (or at least that the angle in between does not change). The scaling looks rather clumsy - applying a constant ratio that is approximately suitable for some configurations can hardly be a general solution.

Comment: Everything is rendered using the same camera